# $\log\det$ asymptotics of a skew-circulant matrix with additive diagonal bimodal disorder

Tags: random-matrices, determinants, statistical-physics, regularization

I'd like to share a problem that I have been dealing with for a longer time now.
In the framework of quenched disorder in the square-lattice Ising model I want to calculate, for large even $M$, the average free energy
\begin{align}\tag{1}\label{eq:F}
\bar F(M)=-\frac 1 2 \, \frac 1 {2^M}\sideset{}{'}\sum_{\{\kappa_m\}=\pm1} \log\det(\mathbf K + \mathbf Q),
\end{align}
with the skew-circulant $M\times M$ matrix
\begin{align}\tag{2}\label{eq:Q}
\mathbf Q = \left[ \frac 1 {M \sin\big(\frac \pi M \big(m-n+\frac 1 2\big)\big)} \right]_{m,n=1}^M
\end{align}
and the diagonal disorder matrix
\begin{align}\tag{3}\label{eq:K}
\mathbf K = \left[ \delta_{m,n}\,\kappa_m\right]_{m,n=1}^M, \quad \kappa_m = \pm 1.
\end{align}
The sum in \eqref{eq:F} has the constraint ($\,'$) that $\prod_{m=1}^M\kappa_m=1$, as else the determinant vanishes.
Note that the set of $\mathbf K$ are the square roots of the identity $\mathbf 1$ under the given constraint, such that $\mathbf Q^T \mathbf Q = \mathbf K^2 = \mathbf 1$.
Therefore, $\det\mathbf Q = \det\mathbf K=1$.

As an example,
\begin{align}\tag{4}\label{eq:F6}
\bar F(6)= -\frac{3}{32} \log \left[\frac{4 \, 2^{2/3}}{3^8}\left(1025-528 \sqrt{3}\right)\right] = 0.20959658\ldots\,.
\end{align}
I can calculate $\bar F(M)$ for $M \lesssim 54$, but the exact enumeration is exponentially complex. I am looking for a better way, with polynomial complexity.

The skew-circulant matrix $\mathbf Q$ can be easily diagonalized by a Fourier transform, with eigenvalues $q_\mu=\frac{\mathrm i \pi \mu}{2M}$, where $\mu$ runs over the odd integers between $-M$ and $M$, leading to equidistant eigenvalues on the unit half circle with positive real part.
So we have the typical case from mathematical physics that we are dealing with two additive contributions, one diagonal in real space and the other diagonal in Fourier space.

The problem can be rewritten in terms of principal minors: Define the matrix dual of $\mathbf Q$, also known as [Cayley transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform),
\begin{align}\tag{5}\label{eq:G}
\mathbf G = \frac{\mathbf 1 - \mathbf Q}{\mathbf 1 + \mathbf Q},
\end{align}
which is a skew-symmetric matrix.
Then,
\begin{align}\tag{6}\label{eq:F2}
\bar F(M) - F_+(M) = -\frac 1 {2^M} \sum_{\{\alpha\}} \log \det \mathbf G(\alpha),
\end{align}
where $\mathbf G(\alpha)$ denotes the submatrix of $\mathbf G$ with row- and column indices $\{\alpha\} = \{(),$ $(1,2),$ $(1,3),$ $\ldots,$ $(1,2,3,4),$ $\ldots,$ $(1,\ldots,M)\}$.
By the constraint, the sum only runs over $\alpha$ with even number of elements, and $\det\{\}=1$.
$F_+(M)$ is the free energy for the case $\kappa_m=+1$.

Hence, $\bar F$ is related to the product of all nonzero principal minors of $\mathbf G$. These minors can be "efficiently" calculated [$O(2^M)$ instead of $O(M^3 2^M)$] using the method described by [Griffin & Tsatsomeros](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2006.04.008), see also [Phys. Rev. B 105, 125104 (2022)](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2104.07638).
Note that using a Schur complement the problem can be further rewritten as a product over *all* principal minors of a $(M-1)\times(M-1)$ matrix.

**Question(s):**

1. Is there a way to exactly (i.e. in polynomial complexity) calculate the leading term
   \begin{align}\tag{Q1}\label{eq:Q1}
   f_\infty = \lim_{M\to\infty} M^{-1} \bar F(M) \approx 0.092084(2) \,?
   \end{align}
2. (optional) Is there a way to exactly calculate the next term
   \begin{align}\tag{Q2}\label{eq:Q2}
   \Delta = \lim_{M\to\infty} \bar F(M) - f_\infty M \,?
   \end{align}

For the two extremal cases $F_\pm(M)$ the expansion around $M=\infty$ can be derived using, e.g., [Euler-Maclaurin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula),
\begin{align}\tag{7a}\label{eq:Fp}
F_+(M) &= -\frac C \pi M - \frac \pi {48M} + O(M^{-3}), \\
F_-(M) &= +\frac C \pi M - \frac 1 2 \log 2 + \frac \pi {48M} +O(M^{-3}), \tag{7b}\label{eq:Fm}
\end{align}
with Catalan's constant $C=0.915966\ldots$.
The free energies of all other configurations $\{\kappa_m\}$ lie between $F_+$ and $F_-$, and $F_+(M) + F_-(M) = -\frac 1 2 \log 2$ for all $M$.

Mathematica code for $\bar F(M)$ from \eqref{eq:F2}:

```
F[M_Integer?EvenQ] := Block[{Q, G, Id = IdentityMatrix[M]},
 Q = Table[1./(M Sin[Pi/M (m - n + 1/2)]), {m, M}, {n, M}];
 G = Inverse[Id + Q].(Id - Q);
 -2^-M Sum[Log@Det@G[[a,a]], {a, Subsets[Range[M], {2, M, 2}]}] +
 - 1/2 Log@Det[Id + Q] ]
```

All comments and ideas are welcome!